# How to capture traffic on local web server?

Tags: windows, localhost, capture

I'm using Windows XP and I've deployed an Apache web server which is listening on port 8080 and address 192.168.2.83. Note that my PC's ip address is 192.168.2.83. I can visit 192.168.2.83:8080 with browser, but I don't know how to capture that visit. When I use wireshark I see no packets.

As I searched the Internet I found some tips like 'setup an virtual loopback adapter' or 'use RawCap to capture on localhost'. But that didn't work for me. I have setup the lp adapter but I can't see it in wireshark. I have tried RawCap but I'm not working on localhost.
I think localhost(=127.0.0.1) is different from my address(=192.168.2.83).

So what should I do?

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve? why are u doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In your case *127.0.0.1* is same as *192.168.2.83*

> On modern computer systems, localhost as a hostname translates to an
>   IPv4 address in the 127.0.0.0/8 (loopback) net block, usually
>   127.0.0.1, or ::1 in IPv6.

Reference: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

So, whatever *wireshark* or *RawCap* will capture or display for *127.0.0.1* is in fact your machines traffic only which is *localhost:8080* or 192.168.2.83:8080

In addition, you can check for *Apache* access log where it records all requests processed by the server, if that helps..

Comment: Did you mean that I should set the capture filter by 'host localhost'?

Comment: Did you mean that I should set the capture filter by 'host localhost'?I've tried that, but still got nothing from wireshark. Can I capture localhost packets with a network adapter whose ip address is 192.168.2.83? Since I cannot get anything from wireshark by setting capture filter 'host localhost'.